# RVM installation + ssh

Tags: ssh, rvm

I have installed RVM (ruby version manager) on a production server (with CentOS).

I have installed it as a user (e.g. foobar) and not as root. (Is this a bad idea?)

Now everything works correctly except that whenever I ssh to my server (e.g. `ssh foobar@example.com`) **RVM doesn't get loaded and I always have to run a login shell** (e.g. `bash --login`) to start using the correct version of ruby and gems.

`.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` for user foobar seems to be properly configured.

I would like to know if this is my fault (a bad configuration), or everyone using RVM is facing this issue.

Comment: Exactly how did you install rvm?

Comment: `$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby` (as seen here: https://rvm.io)

Comment: I have executed that command through ssh (`ssh foobar@example.com` and then I executed that command from the shell; nothing else).

Comment: So what you need to sort out is: why you don't get a login shell when you ssh to the remote host. Contact the system administrator of the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have this problem on my CentOS 6. You need to have a login shell for rvm (if you have installed it as root) installs a `rvm.sh` script under `/etc/profile.d`. This is read by login shells only.